# Camera2api how to access the ultra-wide angle camera?

Tags: android, android-camera2

The phone is pixel7pro and the zoom range is `[0.5563248,30.0]` according to `CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_ZOOM_RATIO_RANGE`

I am using the following code and it is working well when switching to tele lens with `zoom=5.0f`

```
public void setZoom(@NonNull final CaptureRequest.Builder builder, final float zoom)
    {
        if (this.hasSupport == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        final float newZoom = MathUtils.clamp(zoom,  this.minZoom, this.maxZoom);

        final int centerX = this.mSensorSize.width() / 2;
        final int centerY = this.mSensorSize.height() / 2;
        final int deltaX  = (int)((0.5f * this.mSensorSize.width()) / newZoom);
        final int deltaY  = (int)((0.5f * this.mSensorSize.height()) / newZoom);

        this.mCropRegion.set(centerX - deltaX,
                centerY - deltaY,
                centerX + deltaX,
                centerY + deltaY);

        builder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, this.mCropRegion);

        Log.d("zoom","zoom value:"+newZoom+' '+zoom);
    }
```

But it doesn't work with the ultra-wide angle lens with `zoom=0.56f`
Any ideas?

Edited:
The following is the debug log which shows it is working well from x1-x10 (camera 2 and camera 4). But the ultra-wide lens (camera 3) seems not working

:

```
2023-09-22 18:02:07.782   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_capture_session.cc:1084: Supported zoom range is {0.556325, 30}
2023-09-22 18:02:07.782   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_multi_fov_coordinator_hwl.cc:476: ST zoom ratio (min, max): (0.556325, 30)
2023-09-22 18:02:07.856   830-25124 native                  pid-830                              I  I0000 00:00:1695402127.855992   25124 eis_node.cc:1410] Contizoom calibration file: /mnt/vendor/persist/camera/rear/multi_cam_calibration.combined.proto
2023-09-22 18:02:07.857   830-25124 native                  pid-830                              I  I0000 00:00:1695402127.857562   25124 continuous_zoom_factory.cc:586] Check enable_image_based_homography false
2023-09-22 18:02:07.908   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:839: ********************dpm: put camera 2 on NORMAL, frame 0, zoom ratio 1.00 ********************
2023-09-22 18:02:07.908   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:962: ******************** new lead: camera 2(Wide), frame 0, zoom ratio 1.00 *******************
2023-09-22 18:02:07.908   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:1120: Frame number: 0, Lead cam: 2, Zoom ratio: 1.00, APP requested streams: 0, 1, 68948, 
2023-09-22 18:02:07.909   830-11340 Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:1120: Frame number: 1, Lead cam: 2, Zoom ratio: 1.00, APP requested streams: 0, 1, 68948, 
2023-09-22 18:02:35.461 24852-24852 zoom                    com.arkconcepts.cameraserve          D  zoom value:2.0 2.0
2023-09-22 18:02:44.334 24852-24852 zoom                    com.arkconcepts.cameraserve          D  zoom value:5.0 5.0
2023-09-22 18:02:44.858   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:936: ********************dpm: put camera 2 on STANDBY, frame 852, zoom ratio 5.00 *******************
2023-09-22 18:02:44.858   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:839: ********************dpm: put camera 4 on NORMAL, frame 852, zoom ratio 5.00 ********************
2023-09-22 18:02:44.858   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:962: ******************** new lead: camera 4(Tele), frame 852, zoom ratio 5.00 *******************
2023-09-22 18:02:44.859   830-1722  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:1120: Frame number: 852, Lead cam: 4, Zoom ratio: 5.00, APP requested streams: 0, 1, 68948, 
2023-09-22 18:02:44.861   830-1199  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:1120: Frame number: 853, Lead cam: 4, Zoom ratio: 5.00, APP requested streams: 0, 1, 68948, 
2023-09-22 18:02:49.152 24852-24852 zoom                    com.arkconcepts.cameraserve          D  zoom value:10.0 10.0
2023-09-22 18:02:51.155 24852-24852 zoom                    com.arkconcepts.cameraserve          D  zoom value:0.56 0.56
2023-09-22 18:02:51.846   830-1199  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:839: ********************dpm: put camera 2 on NORMAL, frame 938, zoom ratio 1.00 ********************
2023-09-22 18:02:51.846   830-1199  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:936: ********************dpm: put camera 4 on STANDBY, frame 938, zoom ratio 1.00 *******************
2023-09-22 18:02:51.846   830-1199  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:962: ******************** new lead: camera 2(Wide), frame 938, zoom ratio 1.00 *******************
2023-09-22 18:02:51.846   830-1199  Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:1120: Frame number: 938, Lead cam: 2, Zoom ratio: 1.00, APP requested streams: 0, 1, 68948, 
2023-09-22 18:02:51.853   830-22258 Lyric                   pid-830                              I  multicam_whi_request_processor.cc:1120: Frame number: 939, Lead cam: 2, Zoom ratio: 1.00, APP requested streams: 0, 1, 68948, 
2023-09-22 18:02:54.307 24852-24852 zoom                    com.arkconcepts.cameraserve          D  zoom value:1.0 1.0
```

Comment: refer this, this should clear the limitations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197739/11861734